# Using QItemDelegate to show icons in place of text in a table in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qitemdelegate

With PyQt5 I am trying to use QItemDelegate to show an icon instead of a text string in a cell in a table.  Essentially I construct a subclass of the QItemDelegate using:

```
de = MyDelegate(self.attribute_table_view)
```

Here `dself.attribute_table_view` is a `QTableView' object.

I try to draw an icon in every cell in a specific column using:

```
class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):
def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
    QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent, *args)

def paint(self, painter, option, index):

    painter.save()
    value = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)

    line_1x = QPixmap('line_1x.png')

    painter.setBrush(Qt.gray)
    painter.setPen(Qt.black)
    painter.drawPixmap(QRectF(0, 0, 48, 24), line_1x, QRectF(0, 0, 48, 24))
    painter.restore()
```

With the `painter.drawPixmap()` how do I tell it to draw in each cell in the table like one achieves using `painter.drawText(option.rect, Qt.AlignVCenter, value)`?

Also, I have noticed that my current script does not report any errors if I enter a filename that doesn't exist for the .png file.  Should an error by reported if the .png file does not exist?

My current model is a [QgsAttributeTableModel](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableModel.html) and I want to render the current string value for all cells in one column with icon's where the icon used depends on the string value.

Comment: If you place the load of an image in the paint() method the application will become slow since that method is called every time doing the reading of the image at every moment consuming resources, so what is your model? Could you provide a [mcve] ?, depending on the model you show you could indicate how to load the icon to the model. Do you want the icon to be centered in the box?

Comment: I have edited my question to describe the model being used.  I would like the icon to be centred in the box, and, if possible to adjust in size if the box changes in size.

Comment: Do you want it to occupy the entire rectangle or just have the same height?

Comment: Just the same height

Comment: from what I understand, the icons depend on the characteristic of another column

Comment: So they are like icons of A, B, C, if the row meets a characteristic then you want the icon A, if it meets another B and if it is another C, am I correct?

Comment: Is the icon's path the value of the string, or is there only a number of fixed icons?

Comment: Correct, there are only a fixed number of icons like A, B, and C with the a specific icon being displayed when a row meets a characteristic.  At present, the icon's path is not the value of the string - although that is easy for me to implement if that makes the script simpler :)

Comment: okay, I only have one last question, does the column where you want the icon exist in the model ?, that is, what you want is to delete the text of a column and replace it or you want another column to be created.

Comment: The column already exists and I would like to replace it.  However, I am also happy to work with a solution that creates a new column as I can hide the current column.

Comment: some feedback??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180974/discussion-between-philip-whitten-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: First of all I recommend using the fullpath of the image, just to try. If it works for you then the problem will be the path. If the problem is the path, tell me the fullpath of the image and what it returns: `print(QtCore.QDir.currentPath())`

Comment: If you do not point out your errors I can not help you, I see that you are using qgis, and many times the relative routes are relative to the main application, not the plugin.

Comment: I have asked a new question for setting the path for the icon in QGIS here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565084/access-icons-from-within-qgis-plugin

Comment: The path of a file belonging to a .qrc is not real but virtual, so if you want to verify that it exists you should use `print(QtCore.QFileInfo(":/plugins/geomAttribute/line_1x.png").exists())`

Comment: Also to use .qrc in python you must compile it using pyrcc, for example if your .qrc is called some_file.qrc you must execute `pyrcc5 some_file.qrc -o some_file_rc.py` and then import it as `import some_file_rc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this answer I will show several methods, and you can choose according to the complexity of the problem.

#### 1. The number of icons are fixed and one column will be reused.

The logic is to load the icons once, and pass it as an attribute to the delegate, then depending on your logic you get the icon of the list for it modifies `get_icon()` method. and we paint the icon through the `paint()` method of QIcon.

```
class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, icons, parent=None):
        super(MyDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self._icons = icons

    def get_icon(self, index):
        # get the icon according to the condition:
        # In this case, for example, 
        # the icon will be repeated periodically
        icon =  self._icons[ index.row() % len(self._icons) ]
        return icon

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        icon = self.get_icon(index)
        icon.paint(painter, option.rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

How to reuse a column you must use the `setItemDelegateForColumn()` method to set the delegate to a column

```
self.attribute_table_view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
self.attribute_table_view.setModel(your_model)

column_icon = 1
icons = [QtGui.QIcon(QtCore.QDir.current().absoluteFilePath(name)) for name in ["clear.png", "heart.png","marker.png", "pen.png"]]
delegate = MyDelegate(icons, self.attribute_table_view)
self.attribute_table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(column_icon, delegate)
```

[image]

**I have noticed that my current script does not report any errors if I enter a filename that doesn't exist for the .png file. Should an error by reported if the .png file does not exist?**

Qt will not notify if the file does not exist, you have to verify, for example with the `isNull()` function. There are 2 ways to notify:

1. The first one is to return a boolean indicating if the data is loaded or not, but when using a constructor it only returns the constructed object and throws.

2. Launch exceptions, this consumes many resources that Qt considers unnecessary so you will never use it.

Another way that especially Qt notifies that there is an error is through signals but these are only for QObject and QIcon, QPixmap, QImage are not QObjects.

So in conclusion the responsibility to verify or not falls on the developer.